# How does this code I found work? Cipher

Tags: vb.net

So I found this cool cipher, im making a project for school (its kinda like, show us everything you learned kinda of project) and were allowed to get heavy look at other peoples code online (as long is its not a complete copy and paste). I want to understand how it works and make my own version (without copy and pasting), ive put comments for the parts I understand, and question marks for the parts I dont.

```
    Function EncryptDecrypt(ByVal text1 As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal isEncrypt As Boolean) As String //yea got this
        Dim char1 As String //Defining char one
        Dim char2 As String //Defining char two
        Dim cKey As Byte //Defining a key as a byte
        Dim strLength As Integer //Defining strLength as an integer
        Dim Result As String = "" //Defining Result as String equal to nothing
        Dim j As Integer = -1 //Defining j as an integer equal to -1
        If text1 <> "" And IsNumeric(key) Then //if text1 is not nothing and the key is numeric then...
            strLength = text1.Length //making strLength equal to the length of the text.
            For i As Integer = 0 To strLength - 1 //Do until strLenth is less than 1 ???
                char1 = text1.Substring(i, 1) //Char one is equal to 
                If j < key.Length - 1 Then //if j (-1) is less than the key's length - 1 then...
                    j = j + 1 //add one to j
                Else //no explanation needed
                    j = 0 //no explanation needed
                End If //no explanation needed
                cKey = Val(key.Substring(j, 1)) //?? cKey is equal to value of the current character it is looking at (j, 1)??
                If isEncrypt Then //if were encypting it
                   If (Asc(char1) + cKey) > 255 Then //????
                        char2 = Chr(Asc(char1) + cKey - 255) //????
                   Else //no explanation needed
                        char2 = Chr(Asc(char1) + cKey) //??
                   End If //no explanation needed
                Else //no explanation needed
                    If (Asc(char1) - cKey) < 1 Then //????
                        char2 = Chr(Asc(char1) - cKey + 255) //?????
                    Else //no explanation needed
                        char2 = Chr(Asc(char1) - cKey) //?????
                    End If //no explanation needed
                End If //no explanation needed
                Result &= char2 //?????
            Next //no explanation needed
        Else //no explanation needed
            MsgBox("Enter text or key!") //no explanation needed
        End If //no explanation needed
        Return Result //no explanation needed
    End Function //no explanation needed


No explanation needed for these either VVVV
    Private Sub btCrypt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btCrypt.Click
        txtResult.Text = EncryptDecrypt(txtText.Text, txtKey.Text, True)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btDecrypt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btDecrypt.Click
        txtResult.Text = EncryptDecrypt(txtText.Text, txtKey.Text, False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I kinda understand that each "letter" has an "Asc" value, but im not entirely sure how that works. Can anyone help, would be really great and helpful for me!

Comment: We are here to help with programming questions (e.g. fix broken code). we are not here to explain/interpret code for you.

Comment: that's not even how you add comments in VB.NET, the comment symbol you have used is for C# which leads me to believe you haven't even tried. As @MarcB said we are here to help fix code, not write a report for you. How can we explain what the code is doing when you cant even get the comment symbol correct?

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO

Comment: VS comes with a powerful debugger which allows tyou to execute one line of code at a time and watch what happens to variables.  It requires an esoteric device called a *mouse*

Comment: Despite it's name, [Asc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9kb82hd(v=vs.110).aspx) does not use the ASCII character set. If never did in VB classic, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good source of information can be found on the MSDN website. Below are some of the places you where getting stuck on. I've included references to the relivant documenation so if you still don't understand you can go away and see

> ```
>  For i As Integer = 0 To strLength - 1
> ```

Do until strLenth is equal to 0 decrementing 1 at a time

[for loops msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx)

> cKey = Val(key.Substring(j, 1)) //?? cKey is equal to value of the
> current character it is looking at (j, 1)??

Yes, cKey will be assigned the last char of the key. If they key was 854824 then cKey is now '4'.

> If (Asc(char1) + cKey) > 255 Then //????
>
> char2 = Chr(Asc(char1) + cKey - 255) //????
>
> Else //no explanation needed
>
> char2 = Chr(Asc(char1) + cKey) //??
>
> End If //no explanation needed

Here this formula is used for decrying. What is useful to know here is that the Asc function will return the Asci Value for the character ([table here)](http://www.asciitable.com/)

A Asci character of a [Single-byte Character Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374056(v=vs.85).aspx) can not be greater than 255 or less than 0, so if it is greater, then they -255 + the cKey to find the original Ascii value.

> If (Asc(char1) - cKey) < 1 Then //????
>
> char2 = Chr(Asc(char1) - cKey + 255) //?????
>
> Else //no explanation needed
>
> char2 = Chr(Asc(char1) - cKey) //?????
>
> End If //no explanation needed

Same as above but in reverse, this code will encrypt the character value by incrementing 255 to the char value if the ASCII value of char1 - x (where x = the numeric value of the last digit in the cKey) is greater than 0.

> Result &= char2 //?????

and lastly this will concatanate the string onto Result each loop.
This is short hand for writing

> Result = Result + Char2

You'll probably understand it more stepping through the program in debug and seeing the values of the variables as you go along.

Best of luck to you,

hope this helps

Comment: You're frequently dropping the second in in ASCII, making it look more like ANSI. If you make it exactly like ANSI, you'd be correct. The problem is that ANSI isn't one character set. The code is nonsense because it'll encrypt the same string different ways for different users.

Answer (score 1):

It cycles through the input character-by-character, and the key (all numbers, one digit at a time). Each character is converted to its [ASCII character code](http://www.asciitable.com/), and has the key digit added or subtracted from it.

When it runs out of key, it loops back to the start of the key and goes through again.

If adding/subtracting gets a character outside the ASCII character code table (<0 or >255), it wraps round to the other side of the table.

And builds up a string of output, character by character.